# What does the parameter 'site' mean in Joomla getApplication?

Tags: php, joomla

```
$a = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

I came across this in Joomla API:

```
static JApplication getApplication ([mixed $id = null], [array $config = array()], [string $prefix = 'J'])
```

What are the examples of $id, $config and $prefix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$id` can be `'site'` or `'administrator'`. If you don't set it, then if you are on the backend, `JFactory::getApplication('administrator')` will be returned and `JFactory::getApplication('site')` for the frontend.

Depending on the `$id`, either `/administrator/includes/application.php` is included or just `includes/application.php`.

Using `$config` you can set the name of the configuration file, session name sessions etc.

Prefix is class name prefix. All core Joomla classes have been prefixed with J, that's why it is the default setting. For example `JAdministrator`.

Have a look also at http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=/development/tags/1.6.x/1.6.3/libraries/joomla/application/application.php&view=markup for `__construct` and `getInstance` methods of `JApplication` for more details